# Symbolic derivation:

Tags: python

I have made a code for performing symbolic derivation in python as below:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sym

# coeffs = [2, 0, 1]
# p = np.poly1d(coeffs[::-1]) # [::-1] because I want to have poly1d reversed

# print(p)

x = sym.Symbol('x')
p = 2 + x ** 2

print(sym.diff(p))
```

And this one gives me the output `2x` which is correct but I want it to give me the output as `[0,2]`. I would like to define the polynomial as `p = [2,0,1]` instead of `p = 2 + x ** 2` and also have the output on the same formula, ie as a list `[0,2]` and not `2x`. How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you actually try to achieve and why? If you are to work only with polynomials and never display them as formulas, you don't need `sympy` at all. `np.poly1d` has all you need in `p.deriv()`.

Comment: I would like to create a program that performs symbolic derivation. And I would like to define the polynomial as `p = [2,0,1]` instead of `p = 2 + x ** 2` and also have the output on the same formula, ie as `[0,2]` and not `2x`.

Comment: But are you interested only in (one-dimensional) polynomials? Otherwise, how do you intend to represent e.g. `e**x` or `2*x + 3*y`?

Comment: Yes I am only interested in one-dimensional polynomials. But I figured out another way to proceed this - should I post the answer on my own question?

Comment: If you think your answer could be of general use to someone else, then go ahead and post the answer. It is perfectly legal.